# Flink BoundedOutOfOrdernessGenerator watermark issues

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I am trying to build my own implementation of a `BoundedOutOfOrdernessGenerator`, as suggested in [Flink's documentation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/dev/event_timestamps_watermarks.html#with-periodic-watermarks) and I am having some issues in doing so, given that the watermark seems to not be updated correctly. Windows never trigger because the watermark is not advancing.

These are a couple of relevant snippets, where `myWatermarkAssigner` is a `WatermarkGenerator` instance:

**Main stream:**

```
dataLeft = dataLeft.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(myWatermarkAssigner);
dataRight = dataRight.assignTimestampsAndWatermarks(myWatermarkAssigner);

DataStream<MyWindow> output = dataLeft
    .keyBy("field")
    .coGroup(dataRight.keyBy("field"))
    .where(dataL -> dataL.id)
    .equalTo(dataR -> dataR.id)
    .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(duration))
    .apply(myProcessor);
```

**Generator class:**

```
public class WatermarkGenerator<T extends MyEvent> implements AssignerWithPeriodicWatermarks<T> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
    private long maxOutOfOrderness = 15000; // 15 seconds
    private long currentMaxTimestamp;

    public WatermarkGenerator(long maxTimeLag) {
        this.maxOutOfOrderness = maxTimeLag;
    }

    @Override
    public long extractTimestamp(MyEvent element, long previousElementTimestamp) {
        long timestamp = element.eventTime.getTime();
        currentMaxTimestamp = Math.max(timestamp, currentMaxTimestamp);

        return timestamp;
    }

    @Override
    public Watermark getCurrentWatermark() {
        return new Watermark(currentMaxTimestamp - maxOutOfOrderness);
    }
}
```

If I add a simple log inside `getCurrentWatermark()`, these are the results:

```
0
0
0
0
0
1557157602000 // First element just arrived
0
0
0
1557157602000
0
0
0
1557157602000
0
0
0
```

And the windows are never triggered, I understand that is because the watermark is sometimes 0, and some other times the correct value.

Can this be related to the fact that I am using the same instance of `WatermarkGenerator` for `dataLeft` and `dataRight`, and I am only receiving events on `dataLeft`?

Additionally, if I use instead System time for the watermark like this, the windows trigger and the pipeline works like a charm:

```
// return new Watermark(currentMaxTimestamp - maxOutOfOrderness);
return new Watermark(System.currentTimeMillis() - maxOutOfOrderness);
```

As some final notes, I am using `.setAutoWatermarkInterval(1000L)` and I have tried with [the built-in `BoundedOutOfOrdernessTimestampExtractor` implementation](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.8/dev/event_timestamp_extractors.html#assigners-allowing-a-fixed-amount-of-lateness) with the same failed results.

Comment: Hey, what is the `parallelism` that You are running You function with? Also, do You run it locally in IDE or on somekind of cluster ?

Comment: I am not setting any `parallelism` option, so I guess I am running on default settings. I am running the pipeline locally (executed from IntelliJ), using Kinesalite for the input stream.

Comment: Yeah so probably it's the numer of available cores, this may be the reason You are seeing 0's. If You will set it to 1, then output will probably be different.

Comment: But then I understand I would not be benefitting from parallelism, right? I am reluctant to think that this type of `BoundedOutOfOrdernessGenerator` can only be implemented with 1-core setups.

Comment: No, it is not obviously. But setting parallelism to 1 usually helps with debugging. The 0's that are visible, are probably the result of parallelism, for some of the operators, there was indeed no data, so the timestamp was not assigned yet. That's why the watermark is sometimes 0, and some other times the correct value

Comment: I have the same issue too and how to solve it? @dsesto

Comment: On a new iteration of the application I was building, I decided to move to using IngestionTime, where I could stop worrying about timestamp generation. So unfortunately, I do not have an answer to the question @Qoobee

Comment: I am facing the same issue . please help me to resolve this. I am always see watermark value as 9223372036854725808